# I have a gridview with a paging event. Everytime I hit a new page it makes me reload the file from the uploadfile control then it displays new page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want my paging to be seamless, I dont want user to have to reload file to get new pages.Where did I go wrong?

```
    protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            if (FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName == string.Empty)
            {

                return;
            }
            else
            {
                string[] FileExt = FileUpload1.FileName.Split('.');
                string FileEx = FileExt[FileExt.Length - 1];
                if (FileEx.ToLower() == "csv")
                {
                    FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(" " + FileUpload1.FileName));
                }
                else
                {

                    return;
                }
            }
            CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream);
            string[] headers = reader.GetCSVLine();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            foreach (string strHeader in headers)
                dt.Columns.Add(strHeader);
            string[] data;
            while ((data = reader.GetCSVLine()) != null)
                dt.Rows.Add(data);
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                string rowIdNumber = row["Sequence"].ToString();
                string dateAndTime = row["Date and Time"].ToString();
                string personName = row["Description #2"].ToString();
                string doorType = row["Card number"].ToString();

                DateTime dateEntered = Convert.ToDateTime(dateAndTime);
                DoorType doorTypeEnum;

                bool personExists = false;
                foreach (object name in listboxOfNames.Items)
                {
                    if (name.ToString() == personName)
                    {
                        personExists = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!personExists)
                {
                    listboxOfNames.Items.Add(personName);

                }
                switch (doorType)
                {
                    case "A02 - Rear Entrance":
                        doorTypeEnum = DoorType.RearEntranceDoor;
                        break;
                    case "B12 - Exterior Main Floor Man Trap":
                        doorTypeEnum = DoorType.ExteriorMainFloorDoor;
                        break;
                    case "B12 - Interior Main Floor Man Trap":
                        doorTypeEnum = DoorType.InteriorMainFloorDoor;
                        break;
                    case "C13 - Rear Break Room Door":
                        doorTypeEnum = DoorType.RearBreakRoomDoor;
                        break;
                    case "B02 - Exterior Basement Man Trap":
                        doorTypeEnum = DoorType.ExteriorBasementDoor;
                        break;
                    case "B02 - Interior Basement Man Trap":
                        doorTypeEnum = DoorType.InteriorBasementDoor;
                        break;
                    case "D01 - Managed Services Main door":
                        doorTypeEnum = DoorType.ManagedServicesDoor;
                        break;
                    case "D01 - Managed Services Big Door":
                        doorTypeEnum = DoorType.ManagedServicesBigDoor;
                        break;
                    default:
                        doorTypeEnum = DoorType.None;
                        break;
                }
                peopleEntering.Add(new PersonEntered(personName, dateEntered, doorTypeEnum));
            }


            for (int i = 0; i < peopleEntering.Count; i++)
            {
                DateTime startDate = new DateTime();
                DateTime endDate = new DateTime();
                string personName = peopleEntering[i].PersonName;
                if (peopleEntering[i].DoorEntered == DoorType.RearEntranceDoor)
                {
                    startDate = peopleEntering[i].DateOfEntry;
                    for (int j = i + 1; j < peopleEntering.Count; j++)
                    {
                        if (peopleEntering[j].DoorEntered == DoorType.ExteriorBasementDoor && peopleEntering[j].PersonName == personName)
                        {
                            endDate = peopleEntering[j].DateOfEntry;
                        }
                    }

                }
                workSpans.Add(new WorkSpan(personName, startDate, endDate));

            }

            csvReaderGv.DataSource = dt;
            csvReaderGv.DataBind();
            listboxOfNames.Visible = true;

        }

    }

    protected void csvReaderGv_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            csvReaderGv.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
            csvReaderGv.DataBind();
        }

    }
```

what have I done wrong? I have no I idea in my little head why I have to reload file each time I page the gridview.Please add samples or direct me to correct forum or tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

We generally use a GridView Control to Display Data and also Perform Paging, Sorting, Editing, Deleting records. In each of these we have postback on the page.
To avoid Postback during sorting and Paging, the following code can be used inside the GridView Control.

If you have created a GridView and Bind the GridView using data source control, you can avoid postback during sorting and paging by setting **EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks**' property of the GridView to **True**.

**Note** : when you use the 'EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks' property to true for avoid Postback, you cannot use Template Fields in the GridView.

**Example** :

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"AllowSorting = "true"

 DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks = "true">

 <Columns>

  <asp:BoundField DataField="FIRST_NAME" HeaderText="First Name"

                    SortExpression="FIRST_NAME" />

  <asp:BoundField DataField="LAST_NAME" HeaderText="Last Name"

                    SortExpression="LAST_NAME" />

  <asp:BoundField DataField="ADDRESS" HeaderText="Address"

                    SortExpression="ADDRESS" />

 </Columns>

</asp:GridView>
```

or

Check here,

[How to prevent Postback on GridView paging in UpdatePanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469416/how-to-prevent-postback-on-gridview-paging-in-updatepanel)

Comment: Would you or do you have any examples in C#. I have never used VB. Not sure of its syntax.