# Databinder.eval inside gridview inside repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Is there a way to put the following code in a gridview so I can do paging without updating the entire page.

```
<ASP:PANEL id="ResultsPanel" border="1"  HorizontalAlign="Center" runat="server" Width="100%">

<ASP:REPEATER id="SearchResultsRepeater" runat="server" EnableViewState="False">

        <HEADERTEMPLATE>
            <TABLE BORDER="1"  Style="width:800px"" Align="center" >
                <TR>
                    <TD Class="StdSectionHeader2" Style="color: #FFFFFF;" Colspan="8">Select a Provider Name</TD>
                </TR>
                <TR>
                    <TH ID="header1" Class="StdTablePadding5 BlueTD" >Name</TH>
                    <TH ID="header2" Class="StdTablePadding5 BlueTD">Service Area</TH>
                    <TH ID="header4" Class="StdTablePadding5 BlueTD">Gender</TH>
                    <TH ID="header5" Class="StdTablePadding5 BlueTD">City</TH>
                    <TH ID="header6" Class="StdTablePadding5 BlueTD">Zip Code</TH>
                    <TH ID="header7" Class="StdTablePadding5 BlueTD">Processing<BR />Status</TH>
                    <TH ID="header8" Class="StdTablePadding5 BlueTD">Phone</TH>
                </TR>

        </HEADERTEMPLATE>
        <ITEMTEMPLATE>
                <TD Class="StdTablePadding5"><a class="three" href="default.asp" target="_blank">
                    <%# getStartLink(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ServiceAreaName").ToString()  )%>
                    <%# getNextPage(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ServiceAreaName").ToString(),HCQA.ReferralRegistry.UI.Validation.EncodeDigits(((HCQA.ReferralRegistry.UI.User)Session["User"]).EncryptionKey,DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "IndividualID").ToString()))%>
                    <%# getMidLink(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ServiceAreaName").ToString())%>
                    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "IndividualName").ToString()%>
                    <%# getEndLink(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ServiceAreaName").ToString())%></a>
                </TD>

                <TD HEADERS="header2" Class="StdTablePadding5"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ServiceAreaName") %></TD>
                <TD HEADERS="header4" Class="StdTablePadding5"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "gender") %></TD>
                <TD HEADERS="header5" Class="StdTablePadding5"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "city") %></TD>
                <TD HEADERS="header6" Class="StdTablePadding5"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ZipCode") %></TD>
                <TD HEADERS="header7" Class="StdTablePadding5"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ProcessingStatus") %></TD>
                <TD HEADERS="header8" Class="StdTablePadding5"><%# Util.FormatPhoneNumber(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "PhoneNumber").ToString().Trim())%></TD>
            </TR>
        </ITEMTEMPLATE>
        <ALTERNATINGITEMTEMPLATE>
            <TR CLASS="AlternatingItemTemplate">

           <TD HEADERS="header1" Class="StdTablePadding5">
                    <%# getStartLink(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ServiceAreaName").ToString()  )%>
                    <%# getNextPage(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ServiceAreaName").ToString(),HCQA.ReferralRegistry.UI.Validation.EncodeDigits(((HCQA.ReferralRegistry.UI.User)Session["User"]).EncryptionKey,DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "IndividualID").ToString()))%>
                    <%# getMidLink(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ServiceAreaName").ToString())%>
                    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "IndividualName").ToString()%>
                    <%# getEndLink(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ServiceAreaName").ToString())%>
            </TD>
                <TD HEADERS="header2" Class="StdTablePadding5"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ServiceAreaName") %></TD>
                <TD HEADERS="header4" Class="StdTablePadding5"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "gender") %></TD>
                <TD HEADERS="header5" Class="StdTablePadding5"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "city") %></TD>
                <TD HEADERS="header6" Class="StdTablePadding5"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ZipCode") %></TD>
                <TD HEADERS="header7" Class="StdTablePadding5"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ProcessingStatus") %></TD>
                <TD HEADERS="header8" Class="StdTablePadding5"><%# Util.FormatPhoneNumber(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "PhoneNumber").ToString().Trim())%></TD>
            </TR>
        </ALTERNATINGITEMTEMPLATE>
        <FOOTERTEMPLATE>
      </table>
   </FOOTERTEMPLATE>
    </ASP:REPEATER>
```

Comment: Yes there is. Check [these tutorials](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=gridview+tutorial+asp.net).

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "put the following code in a gridview".  Do you mean, "convert this table, constructed via a repeater, into a gridview"?

Comment: Standard Gridview is doint postbacks for paging. If you want to partially update your page (i.e. just the gridview) you could use an updatepanel (ajax). This was answered a lot of times already so I link one possible approach here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469416/how-to-prevent-postback-on-gridview-paging-in-updatepanel